# Generic method takes KeyValuePair. How do I forward the call to the correct overload taking the Key type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        void DoSomething(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("int");
        }
        void DoSomething(char a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("char");
        }
        void DoSomething<T, U>(KeyValuePair<T, U> a)
        {
            DoSomething(a.Key);
        }
    }
```

I have a third-party assembly that has a huge struct with lots of members of different types in it. I need to take some of the values from that struct and process them. So I write overloads for different types. I know what I need to do with ints, with chars, etc. And if some value is a key value pair, I know I need to process only the key the same way I would process a primitive value. The code above is my failed attempt to do so. The problem is that the C# compiler complains that it cannot determine which overload to call for `a.Key` because, unlike C++, where it would instantiate the template and then automagically know exactly which overload to call or fail with a compiler error, C# doesn't do this.

Is there something basic I'm missing, and if not, what is the usual C# idiom to solve the design problem I'm facing?

Comment: You'll probably need a pattern matched switch or `is`/`as`/cast to *each* known type which will get potentially long and cumbersome. You can always use `dynamic`, though that has its pitfalls as well.

Comment: Well, at compile time you don´t know *anything* about neither `T` nor `U`, that´s why the compiler can´t infer the right type. You´d have to cast to the specifc type, e.g. `DoSomething((int)a.Key)`. This makes your method pretty useless IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hacky way is to cast `a.Key` to dynamic:

```
DoSomething((dynamic)a.Key);
```

The correct overload will be determined at runtime. If there are no appropriate overloads then you will get an exception.

Comment: Does this have much runtime overhead?

Comment: It has some overhead because CLR needs to figure out which overload to call at runtime, but it shouldn't be too noticeable if you are not calling this method too many times like hundreds of thousands.

Comment: There is also some overhead because of the boxing involved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are 100% confident that `T` will be `int` or `char` - then `dynamic` is one approach to consider:

```
static void DoSomething<T, U>(KeyValuePair<T, U> a)
{
    dynamic bob = a.Key;
    DoSomething(bob);
}
```

Comment: Does this have much runtime overhead?

Comment: It has some, yes. You would need to profile it to see whether it is impactful in your context.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with e.g. the `dynamic` approach is that it gives you a runtime error. Having generic code that compiles but produces a runtime error due to type mismatches always feels like a "lie" to me - if you cannot express it as a type parameter constraint and have the compiler fail the compilation, you shouldn't write that generic method.

I would instead supply two methods:

```
    void DoSomething<U>(KeyValuePair<int, U> a)
    {
        DoSomething(a.Key);
    }
    void DoSomething<U>(KeyValuePair<char, U> a)
    {
        DoSomething(a.Key);
    }
```

Now you can only supply `KeyValuePair`s that we know how to correctly deal with, and anything else goes back to generating compile-time errors. I prefer the slight redundancy<sup>1</sup> to get the error at compile time.

---

Of course, in the above, the utility of these methods is somewhat questionable but in a larger code base you may still be able to abstract *some* functionality into a private generic method that both of these `DoSomething` methods defer to.

---

<sup>1</sup>And of course there's only "apparent" redundancy in the source code. In the compiled IL for these methods, the references to the other `DoSomething` methods are different, since overload resolution will produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 7.1, you can use the `is` operator with an output variable to accomplish this.  This still has the drawback of `dynamic` in that the error thrown will be a runtime error vs a compile time error but it eliminates the CLR overhead of using dynamic.

```
private void DoSomething<T, U>(KeyValuePair<T, U> a)
{
    if (a.Key is int keyInt)
    {
        DoSomething(keyInt);
    }
    else if (a.Key is char keyChar)
    {
        DoSomething(keyChar);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to DoSomething to a.Key");
    }
}
```

---

And the same thing, but prettier because `switch` statement.

```
private void DoSomething<T, U>(KeyValuePair<T, U> a)
{
    switch (a.Key)
    {
        case int keyInt:
            DoSomething(keyInt);
            break;
        case char keyChar:
            DoSomething(keyChar);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unable to DoSomething to a.Key");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this in the "major" version C# 7.0 also, not just in 7.1.

Comment: The `is` operator works great in C# 7.0, but using it with generics, as seen above yields the following error "An expression of type 'T' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'int' in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater."

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right! So with e.g. `object key`, you _can_ say `key is int keyInt` already in C# 7.0, but with `T key` where `T` is a type parameter, you need C# 7.1 for that.